# Laravel Signed Routes throws InvalidSignatureException in production

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I use visit a URL created with `temporarySignedRoute()` on *production*, it throws `InvalidSignatureException`. However, when in *dev* environment, it works. I have also tried using `signedRoute()` with no luck.

I am creating my URLs like this:

```
\URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'user.activate', 
    now()->addHours(200), 
    [ 'id' => $user->id ]
);
```

Example of URL: https://xx.xx/activate/5?expires=1537065074&signature=f57713b2fccea5ce17b7c1a3241e275d62f1994cd8004ea480cced2402081090

I have made sure that the `APP_KEY` is set. I'm not really sure what step I should take in order to fix this. I am using Laravel Forge for deployment. I am also using a Load Balancer but only one app server atm.

> Why is `temporarySignedRoute()` throwing `InvalidSignatureException` in production?

**Edit:**

Logging the request, I get this data:

```
// [ $expired, $url, $query, $original, $signature ]
[
 false,
 "http://xx.xx/activate/13",{"expires":"1537076308","signature":"9d972a574137bf7e5f30120c3f539a81bca71875020c3476e3bfb230220a73f7"},
 "http://xx.xx/activate/13?expires=1537076308",
 "ed80a6ae717e806fd5f887224c2ac88f5fffb893ae284cc52688ba0690d3a9e1"
]
```

Notice that the URL starts with `http://` but the actual link generated is using `https://`. The URL is logged with `request()->url()`. Which leads me to believe that the problem lies in the http-scheme.

In my `AppServiceProvider.php` I am forcing https like this:

```
if (env('APP_ENV') == 'production') {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Why is `request()` receiving it as non-http?

Comment: Presumably the time is set correctly on your production server?

Comment: Yes, executing `date` returns `Fri Sep  7 21:16:28 UTC 2018`. But the date shouldn't really matter, right?

Comment: I have added some debugging info if you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by my load balancer not sending HTTPS calls to the server. Meaning the server was hashing a different URL-scheme (http) than the original (https).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and Fredrik's answer helped.

When I dumped the request while generating the signed url, I saw that my server was requesting from "http" rather than "https" even though the site was served over "https". I had to change my Cloudflare settings to force https on requests...